# Simple Scala Function Not Removing Double Spaces

Tags: scala

For some reason when I input a string with double spaces such as "  ", the function does not remove them from the string, nor does it remove them when they are generated by two WUB's in a row

For example:

songDecoder("WUBCATWUBWUBBALLWUB") outputs "CAT_ _BALL" (underscores represent spaces)

I could fix this by other means, but since I have no idea why my current code isn't working I figured I should ask to patch my understanding.

```
def songDecoder(song:String):String = {
  val l = song.indexOf("WUB")

  if (song.contains("  ")) {
    val e = song.indexOf("  ")
    songDecoder(song.patch(e,Nil,1))
  }

  if (l==0) {
    val c = song.patch(l,Nil,3)
    songDecoder(c)
  }
  if (l== -1)
    song.trim
  else {
    val c = song.patch(l,Nil,2)
    val b = c.patch(l," ",1)
    songDecoder(b)
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want the code to do. Please explain in more detail

Comment: Do you expect your output to be `CATBALL`?

Comment: the goal is to remove the double space and leave a normal space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because when you call a recursive method it eventually returns with its result. The code that clears out the double-whitespace doesn't save that result.

```
if (song.contains("  ")) {
  val e = song.indexOf("  ")
  songDecoder(song.patch(e,Nil,1)) //send patched song to decoder
}                                  //don't save returned string
//continue with unpatched song
```

The 2nd `if` block also recurses without saving the result.

```
if (l==0) {
  val c = song.patch(l,Nil,3)
  songDecoder(c)  //send patched song to decoder
}                 //don't save returned string
//continue with unpatched song
```

You can remove both of those `if` blocks and you'll get the same results from your method. The only code that effects the output is the final `if`/`else` and that's because it is at the end of the method's code block. So whatever the `if`/`else` produces that's what the method returns.

```
if (l== -1)
  song.trim  //return the final result string
else {
  val c = song.patch(l,Nil,2) //remove one WUB
  val b = c.patch(l," ",1)    //replace with space
  songDecoder(b)  //return whatever the next recursion returns
}
```

---

Just as an FYI, here's a different approach.

```
def songDecoder(song:String):String =
  "(WUB)+".r.replaceAllIn(song, " ").trim
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why it doesn't save since the else clause and the second if clause save and remove the WUB's

Comment: @MatthewWyatt; I've expanded the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
song.split(“(WUB)+”).mkString(“ “).trim
```